# How to take an Average of + or - SD

Tags: r, statistics

I have data where the [1] dependent variable is taken from a controlled and independent variable [2] then independent variable. The `mean` and `SD` are taken from [1].

(a) and this is the result of `SD`:

```
   Year        Species Pop_Index                      
1  1994   Corn Bunting  2.082483                        
5  1998   Corn Bunting  2.048155                     
10 2004   Corn Bunting  2.061617                      
15 2009   Corn Bunting  2.497792                       
20 1994      Goldfinch  1.961236 
25 1999      Goldfinch  1.995600 
30 2005      Goldfinch  2.101403 
35 2010      Goldfinch  2.138496 
40 1995 Grey Partridge  2.162136
```

(b) And the result of `mean`:

```
   Year        Species Pop_Index
1  1994   Corn Bunting  2.821668
5  1998   Corn Bunting  2.916975
10 2004   Corn Bunting  2.662797
15 2009   Corn Bunting  4.171538
20 1994      Goldfinch  3.226108
25 1999      Goldfinch  2.452807
30 2005      Goldfinch  2.954816
35 2010      Goldfinch  3.386772
40 1995 Grey Partridge  2.207708
```

(c) This is the Code for `SD`:

```
structure(list(Year = c(1994L, 1998L, 2004L, 2009L, 1994L, 1999L, 
2005L, 2010L, 1995L), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Corn Bunting", "Goldfinch", "Grey Partridge"
), class = "factor"), Pop_Index = c(2.0824833420524, 2.04815530904537, 
2.06161673349657, 2.49779159320587, 1.96123572400404, 1.99559986715288, 
2.10140285528351, 2.13849611018009, 2.1621364896722)), row.names = c(1L, 
5L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 25L, 30L, 35L, 40L), class = "data.frame")
```

(d) This is the code for `mean`:

```
structure(list(Year = c(1994L, 1998L, 2004L, 2009L, 1994L, 1999L, 
2005L, 2010L, 1995L), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Corn Bunting", "Goldfinch", "Grey Partridge"
), class = "factor"), Pop_Index = c(2.82166841455814, 2.91697463618566, 
2.66279663056763, 4.17153795031277, 3.22610845074252, 2.45280743991572, 
2.95481600904799, 3.38677188055508, 2.20770835158744)), row.names = c(1L, 
5L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 25L, 30L, 35L, 40L), class = "data.frame")
```

(e) And this is the code used to take the `mean` of `mean` `Pop_Index` over the years:

```
df2 <- aggregate(Pop_Index ~ Year, df1, mean)
```

(f) And this is the result:

```
  Year Pop_Index
1 1994  3.023888
2 1995  2.207708
3 1998  2.916975
4 1999  2.452807
5 2004  2.662797
6 2005  2.954816
7 2009  4.171538
8 2010  3.386772
```

Now it wouldn't make sense for me to take the average of `SD` by doing the same procedure as before with the `function` `mean` or `SD`.

I have looked online and found someone in a similar predicament with this data:

Month:   January
Week 1 Mean: 67.3 Std. Dev: 0.8
Week 2 Mean: 80.5 Std. Dev: 0.6
Week 3 Mean: 82.4 Std. Dev: 0.8

And the response:
"With equal samples size, which is what you have, the standard deviation you are looking for is:
Sqrt [ (.64 + .36 + .64) / 3 ] = 0.739369"

How would I do this in R, or is there another way of doing this? Because I want to plot error bars and the dataset plotted is like that of (f), and it would be absurd to plot the SD of (a) against this because the vector lengths would differ.

---

Sample from original `data.frame` with a few columns and many rows not included:

```
structure(list(GRIDREF = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("SP8816", "SP9212", "SP9322", 
"SP9326", "SP9440", "SP9513", "SP9632", "SP9939", "TF7133", "TF9437"
), class = "factor"), Lat = c(51.83568688, 51.83568688, 51.79908899, 
51.88880822, 51.92476157, 52.05042795, 51.80757645, 51.97818159, 
52.04057068, 52.86730817, 52.89542895), Long = c(-0.724233561, 
-0.724233561, -0.667258035, -0.650074995, -0.648996758, -0.630626734, 
-0.62349292, -0.603710436, -0.558026241, 0.538966197, 0.882597783
), Year = c(2006L, 2007L, 1999L, 2004L, 1995L, 2009L, 2011L, 
2007L, 2011L, 1996L, 2007L), Species = structure(c(4L, 7L, 5L, 
10L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 1L), .Label = c("Blue Tit", "Buzzard", 
"Canada Goose", "Collared Dove", "Greenfinch", "Jackdaw", "Linnet", 
"Meadow Pipit", "Robin", "Willow Warbler"), class = "factor"), 
    Pop_Index = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 8L)), row.names = c(1L, 
100L, 1000L, 2000L, 3000L, 4000L, 5000L, 6000L, 10000L, 20213L, 
30213L), class = "data.frame")
```

A look into this `data.frame`:

```
      GRIDREF      Lat       Long Year        Species Pop_Index TempJanuary
1      SP8816 51.83569 -0.7242336 2006  Collared Dove         0    2.128387
100    SP8816 51.83569 -0.7242336 2007         Linnet         0    4.233226
1000   SP9212 51.79909 -0.6672580 1999     Greenfinch         2    5.270968
2000   SP9322 51.88881 -0.6500750 2004 Willow Warbler         0    4.826452
3000   SP9326 51.92476 -0.6489968 1995  Collared Dove         1    4.390322
4000   SP9440 52.05043 -0.6306267 2009        Jackdaw         0    2.934516
5000   SP9513 51.80758 -0.6234929 2011   Meadow Pipit         1    3.841290
6000   SP9632 51.97818 -0.6037104 2007   Canada Goose         4    7.082580
10000  SP9939 52.04057 -0.5580262 2011        Buzzard         0    3.981290
20213  TF7133 52.86731  0.5389662 1996          Robin         0    3.532903
30213  TF9437 52.89543  0.8825978 2007       Blue Tit         8    7.028710
```

Comment: Frankly, taking the `mean` of the means is problematic unless you are certain that the number of observations within each group is identical.

Comment: I think this question is much more fitting for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) ... and I'll be interested in the responses you get :-)

Comment: The `dataset` I am working with has the population of birds taken at various sites all within the same region. Would it then be acceptable to take these mean observations of say 16 individual species and grouping them under a category such as Generalist, then taking the mean average of this entire population against Year sighted from 1994 to 2013. Would this be acceptable in taking the means of mean? such that a 'Grand mean'. Apologies if this isn't in the right section. I am more concerned with implementing the stats on R but I want to be sure the statistics is correct.

Comment: The only time that mean-of-means is accurate/appropriate is when the weighting is uniform (or correctly weighted). Think of it this way: if you have a sample of 1000 birds with a mean of 3, and a sample of 10 birds with a mean of 6, your overall incorrect mean is 4.5, when in reality it is `((1000*3)+(10*6))/(1000+10)` (3.030). If your data above includes the number of observations for each group, then you can do a weighted-mean, perhaps with `Hmisc::wtd.mean(c(3, 6), c(1000, 10))`.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  You  cannot add sd, but you can add variance, which is where the answer about the root of the sum of the squares comes from.  But that is based on independent measurements of similar data.  If I'm understanding your question, you are looking at a different beast- you don't have equal sample sizees, and you are combining different groups. I think you need to figure out what you are going for and reframe.

Comment: @r2evans So can I take all the species that correspond to the same value of `Pop_Index` and connect that with years then take the weighted average? Or is it the amount of times the Species Occur so Turtle Dove occurs 10 times in year 1994 and blackbird 8 times. The `Pop_Index` of Turtle Dove varies after each sighted occurrence, as does blackbird. Do I take the sum of `Pop_Index` and times that by the occurrence of a single species then the same for the other, add the two together and divide by the total number of species?

Comment: *"the same value of Pop_Index"* makes no sense to me, grouping by a mean is somewhat meaningless (pun intented). The only way you can take a mean of means without bias is to know the group sizes. It definitely sounds like I don't know enough about your source data to be able to give you a definitive answer, but I *do* feel that you really need to reframe your question (along with what @BrianFisher said).

Comment: @r2evans I have added the original `data.frame` what is your interpretation? The dataset has been taken from DEFRA and noticed they have done it in a similar or same way, by using geometric means which I have also been doing. Here's a pdf link: https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/471746/A_brief_introduction_to_the_Wild_Birds_Populations_indicator__4_.pdf

Comment: @Meilton can you be clear what you are trying to accomplish? One of the problems we are having is the mean of pop_index seems meaningless given information provided. Are you looking for the average number of observations of all species per site, or some index of number of species per site, or something else?   Given that you have the base data, does it make sense to calculate the desired descriptive stats based off of the raw data rather than trying to aggregate summary stats?

Comment: @BrianFisher Simply: 1. the means of population by species matched to their respective years. My colleague, 2. Then having grouped these into two categories, generalist and specialist of bird species, has taken the means of population belonging to those birds whose means were taken respective to their years resulting in (f). Now, realising the implications with this, is there a way to revive this? The original question is to know whether the birds decline or increase over the years which has been altered into whether generalist or specialist decline or increase over the years.

Comment: Which is what led me into thinking that I could do 1 as well as 2. Unless there is another way around this statistically that can be shown through R? This is what led me to the question, can the means of means be taken? if so, can the means of SD also be taken? and that leads onto point 2, so I could plot it as error bars.

Comment: Meilton, I think your reply to Brian further cements my recommendation to take this over to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), at least for the *conceptual* analysis you want to do. It does not appear to be a question of how to code things as much to determine if the summarization is valid.